# Material UI not working with JSPM

Tags: reactjs, jspm

I am unable to use React add-ons with JSPM but React itself is working.
JSPM throws this error:

```
Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Error loading "react-addons-{addon}" at http://localhost:3000/react-addons-{addon}.js
```

This problem appears when I try to use the Material-UI in my project.

Comment: So I answer myself.  JSPM found require in comment and resolve it as a legal require! The only way is to  remove comment from the node package.

Comment: i have the same problem. could you elaborate please on where you found the comment that needs to be removed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the work around `import React from 'react/lib/ReactWithAddons'` That's gonna work because basically you load that file from the lib but I think React will remove those addons and create some npm packages for them. I really don't know why so I hope this at least work for you, for now.

More information:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/680
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2909

Answer (score 0):

I never encountered this problem, but I have another issue. My setup is :

- jspm
- babel for ES6

1) installed material-ui with `jspm install material-ui=npm:material-ui`

2) this gave me the ability to import material ui into my React Component files like this : `import {TextField, LeftNav} from 'material-ui'`

At this point I get the right references into my ES6 file, so if I do a 
    console.log(TextField); 
I get the react component printed.

Sadly my current issue is that I'm getting errors when trying to use the component in jsx

```
   return (
     <div>
       <TextField />
     </div>
   )
```

throws an error :

```
Warning: getDefaultProps is only used on classic React.createClass definitions. Use a static property named `defaultProps` instead.
warning.js:17 Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead. See: http://fb.me/react-legacyfactory
warning.js:26 Warning: TextField(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render` in your component or you may have accidentally tried to render an element whose type is a function that isn't a React component.
warning.js:17 Warning: Don't set the props property of the component. Mutate the existing props object instead.
dashboard:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Can't add property context, object is not extensible
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app.js
    at ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent
```

Maybe this would help people move past this issue.